# kubectl get pods -A The connection to the server 172.31.46.185:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, devops

I have been setting up the kubernetes cluster in ec2 ubuntu instance. I have opened the required ports such as 6443 and others to communicate. But, Idk why i am getting connection refused. May be the calio cni getting issue. Because when I do applying the flannel .yaml file apiserver and controll manager pods running successfully. Here is the log.

```
kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE      NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-b7c2w                      0/1     Pending            0               2m6s
kube-system    coredns-5d78c9869d-cbc7x                   0/1     Pending            0               4m37s
kube-system    coredns-5d78c9869d-d89hz                   0/1     Pending            0               4m37s
kube-system    etcd-ip-172-31-46-185                      1/1     Running            2 (2m44s ago)   5m47s
kube-system    kube-apiserver-ip-172-31-46-185            1/1     Running            1 (5m14s ago)   5m11s
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-ip-172-31-46-185   1/1     Running            2 (3m8s ago)    4m11s
kube-system    kube-proxy-rgm5g                           0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   3 (17s ago)     4m38s
kube-system    kube-scheduler-ip-172-31-46-185            0/1     Running            5 (94s ago)     4m14s
```

[Here is the blog link which I am folowing to setup the cluster:](https://medium.com/@mehmetodabashi/installing-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-20-04-e49c43c63d0c)

Any suggestion would be helpful :)

Comment: Hey since there are are some pods on pending and one CrashLoopBackOff can you provide the logs not only the list of pods?

Comment: Hey.also kubectl get events.

Comment: Hi Guys It got resolved may be the networking and gpg-key issue. Thanks for your comments.